# PHP - Button bringing me to a totally different page

Tags: php

I made a register page and for some reason, when people hit the button to register, it brings them to a different page than what I told the code to bring them to.

```
<form action="../scripts/registerparse.php" method="post">
    Username <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    Password <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    Confirm Password <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" />
    Full Name <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" />
    Email <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    Gamertag <input type="text" name="gamertag" id="gamertag" />
    Console <select name="console">
                <option value="XBox360">XBOX 360</option>
                <option value="Playstation3">PS3</option>
            </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Create Your Account Now" name="submit2" id="submit2" />
</form>
```

The code tells the person to go to "registerparse.php", but it brings the person to "loginparse.php". Does anyone have an idea on why it is doing this?

Comment: maybe registerparse.php theres a redirection being made to loginparse.php

Comment: @KAii Here is the code for registerparse.php: http://pastebin.com/VtQkhUKe
Sorry for the link, but it would not have fit into the character limit.

Comment: You can use Firebug/Chrome devtools to track requests.

Comment: check whether javascript is submit a form

Answer (score 0):

Check your `registerparse.php`

if theres a condition set to go `loginparse.php`

to see if something redirects your page from `registerparse.php`

Open the page from Firefox then open `Firebug`

in firebug enable `NET` Console then click your submit button where the  form is

You will see if your form does go to `registerparse.php` before going to `loginparse.php`

or directly going to `loginparse.php`

**2 Things to check from the output of debbuging in** `firebug`.

1 . If your forms goes to `registerparse.php` before going to `loginparse.php` you should check your `loginparse.php`
if there is any redirection being made..

2 . If your forms goes directly to `loginparse.php` check the file where your forms is for some javascripts
that maybe the issue while form is directly submitting.

Comment: Here is the code for registerparse.php: pastebin.com/VtQkhUKe Sorry for the link, but it would not have fit into the character limit.

Comment: it seems there aint any redirection done on your registerparse.php. try to debug it to see whether it is directly go through loginparse.php via firebug

Comment: heres an image to enable your NET console then submit the form . http://imgur.com/XtPtrB9. Then after the form is submitted request made can see under it.. In there you will see how where did your form goes.

Comment: it goes straight to the loginparse.php page

Comment: go to the file where your form is and search for loginparse.php . That will help you find whose redirection your page through..